Short story about a traveler who receives shelter, but after some dialogue, the traveler turns out to be a ghost or maybe Odin
It was told from the point of the view of the ghost traveler at first.  It felt like folklore, and I think there was some sort of test that was failed during the dialogue where the true nature of the traveler tipped its hand.

In roughly which year did you read this? And did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

I think I read it in either a collection of short stories or it was at the back or beginning of a normal book. I think i read it 6-8 years ago, this is only a guess though.

There are tales from the Norse folklore on this theme. One is a riddle contest between a (blind?) man and a king: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A1tur_Gestumblinda. The other is how king Geirröth put a wanderer called Grimnir to the torture, because he had been advised he was a powerful magician: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%ADmnism%C3%A1l. In both cases the surprise guest turned out to be Odin.

Oh, and there is also the contest between Odin and Vafthrund: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaf%C3%BEr%C3%BA%C3%B0nir however the reader knows right from the start the guest is Odin.

[Insert myth here].  The ancient gods tended to do this a lot.

There are several stories (sagas, to be specific), where Odin appears in disguise. This is not an uncommon story. I'm not sure the question contain enough information to pin it down to a specific saga/edda.

@Flater yet Grímnismál fits all the details provided, whereas the other stories do not. It is spoken from Grímnir's point of view and Grímnir/Odin vanishes in the end. The story has also a test: no hound is fierce enough to attack Grímnir, which proves him a dangerous sorcerer.

This is probably "The Sorrow of Odin the Goth" by poul-anderson, part of his Time Patrol series. It was part of a fixup called Time Patrolman.
This features Professor Carl Furness, who has been time-traveling for historical research among ancient Germanic Tribes, and is recruited by Time Patrolman Manse Everard to perform a task to help preserve the timeline. Through a series of  misadventures, Furness slips into the character of Odin, the Wanderer.
Another Poul Anderson story featuring (a different) Odin is "The Golden Slave".

thank you for your reply, i edited my original post because i was mixing the disk by Borges into the story i am looking for, which had a relative of Odin. Your answer sounds cool though.
